# How do I configure Jenkins Maven Repository Plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins

I "installed" the Maven Repository Plugin in jenkins via web gui, however when I click on Maven Repository icon which appeared in menu after, I get 404 error... What am I missing?

Comment: I have this exact problem, and it looks like it has been reported in the Jenkins Jira: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17495.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Jenkins log file. Jenkins is probably throwing an exception somewhere when gathering the data needed to respond to the browser request. I got this problem when I had a particularly large artifact which Jenkins, when attempting to calculate its checksum, threw an `OutOfMemory` exception.